# python send message in messenger using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I tried using the following code , I have to manually open the messenger window , It did send the message but after it send one time, it will return me the following error , 
 'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
 return self._parent.execute(command, params)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Image\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')

for i in range(99):
    name = input('Enter the name of user or group : ')
    msg = input('Enter your message : ')
    count = int(input('Enter the count : '))
    input('Enter anything after scanning QR code')
  #  user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))
  #  user.click()

    msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("_1mf._1mj")

    for i in range(count):
        msg_box.send_keys(msg," 第",i,"次")
        button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_30yy._38lh._7kpi')
        button.click()
```

Comment: howtf whyyy it cannot send

Answer (score 0):

Only ***input*** element can sendKeys.

But the element you try to sendKeys is ***div***.
[image]

I think that the messenger cannot automatically send message with Selenium.

You can try to use Messenger API to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The real matter is that you have to take another element to send keys the xpath of the element is `//div[@aria-label="Aa"]` so the line to find it will be

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@aria-label="Aa"]')
```

Liked to help you.